# I'm trying to create a multi-table Query on MS Access. Both tables contain dates but at different frequency

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to create a Multi-Table Query on Access to improve operational efficiency.

I have two Tables:

- EPOS (where: Date/Item Code/Sales for the day are contained on a daily basis)
- MATERIAL (where: Date/Item Code/Opening Stock for the day are contained on a weekly basis)

I have Daily data for EPOS (Sales), but only Weekly data for MATERIAL (Opening Stock).

I'm trying to Run a Query that allows me to filter by item code in the [Design View,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cId8U.png) and display daily data for EPOS and just weekly data for Opening Stock.

I'm trying to have it displayed [at this frequency,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIamE.png) with Opening Stock being shown just for where data is available.

When I've tried, my data would only be displayed on a Weekly Frequency (basically, only where Opening Stock information is available).
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiMZL.png)

I tried my best to make my request as clear and concise as possible, any questions, please ask.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Should provide sample data and desired output as text tables in question, not images. Tool for building markdown formatted tables - https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables. Or post SQL statements for building tables.

Comment: Edit question to show attempted SQL statement. Perhaps just need to change the JOIN type.

Comment: Don't use date as a column name.  I'll call it WeeklyDate  it looks like you need to [GroupBy]  WeeklyDate.  This is easy, but you haven't shown what you want.  So google "group by" and access.  Then watch some videos.  Then play with the totals row in the query designer which you open with a right click or by selecting totals from the ribbon.